# Azure AD Cypress authentication

Tags: typescript, testing, azure-active-directory, automated-tests, cypress

im trying to get past Azure authentication to log into my web app. I tried couple of things but cant get it work.

This simple command:

```
cy.visit(myPage);
  cy.origin(
    azureAdPage,
    { args: { username: currentUsername, password: currentPassword } },
    ({ username, password }) => {
      cy.get('input[type="email"]').should('be.visible').type(username);
      cy.get('input[type="submit"]').should('be.visible').click();
      cy.get('input[type="password"]').should('be.visible').type(password);
      cy.get('input[type="submit"]').should('be.visible').click();
      cy.get('#idBtn_Back').should('be.visible').click();
    },
  );
```

Ends up with:

AADSTS9002327: Tokens issued for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type may only be redeemed via cross-origin requests.

for:
[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BtenantId%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token)

I also tried to get token before entering website and storing it in localStorage, but it didnt work. (token from response is valid, i checked that in Postman)

Also tried [this](https://github.com/juunas11/AzureAdUiTestAutomation/blob/main/UiTestAutomation.Cypress/cypress/support/auth.js) approach, but again im not authorized when entering my website.

I ran out of ideas, so ill apreciate any help.
Im running on the newest Cypress version (12.14.0)
Logging with this user manually works fine, this only occur during cypress test.

Comment: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/end-to-end-testing/azure-active-directory-authentication -> Have you tried the steps in this guide? At a quick glance, they're slightly different from the approaches you've described above.

Comment: yes and im still getting error for token endpoint

Comment: @teddy any luck ? I am also facing similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i had to set chromeWebSecurity to true.